# finding the general solution of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Under what conditions does the solution of the following system exist?

How can one find the general solution of the linear system $$\frac{dX(t)}{dt}=A(t)X(t)+B(t)$$ where:
- $A(t)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of functions of $t$,
- $X(t)$ is an $n \times 1$ unknown matrix,
- $B(t)$ is also an $n \times 1$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You may treat it as a simple differential equation like $y'=f(x)y+g(x)$. I think the same conditions are needed to have an answer. And the same technique would work to get the answer.

Comment: There is a radical change whenever $\mathrm{A}\left(t\right)\mathrm{A}\left(t'\right) \not= \mathrm{A}\left(t'\right)\mathrm{A}\left(t\right)$ if $t \not= t'$.